# Where do you put python code for hooks

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

I have created a python script I want a mercurial hook to call but what I cant figure out is where the working directory (or where to start the path to the script) should be from.

I know this probably isnt right but I need a way to set a hook like...
changegroup=python:e:\www\hg\hooks\teamTrack.py:associate

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you put the python file in your python path you can reference it by name without a path in the hgrc.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out I got it right eventually the thing is I didn't realize the working directory (where my output was going) was the base of the repo.